# Is it possible to use redis_store output plugin for fluentd to handle huge amount of logs?

Tags: redis, fluentd

I'm trying to configure fluentd to send logs to redis on different server (the path is fluentbit-fluentd-redis-logstash-elastic), but I can't figure out some performance issues. If I save logs only on disc, everything is ok, all logs are saved (thousands per sec), but if I add redis_store section, the same amount of data makes fluentd much slower and the memory is still growing until next restart (day or two).
I know that it's probably because of input is faster than output, but how to handle that, how to send so many data to redis? Add more memory is not solution it can only add some time. Is it because redis can't receive data from so many threads (but redis is not overloaded, there is no queue)? I dont know if that is network issue (but in this plugin i cant try another protocol?), cpu issue (cpu is on cca 70%), or the plugin itself?
If I add redis plugin, the communication with redis is just so slow that fluentd is not fast enough and add data to memory.

Config

```
<system>
  workers 4
  root_dir /fluentd/log/buffer/
</system>

<worker 0-3>
<source>
 @type forward
  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 9880
</source>

<label @TEST>
<match test.**> 
 @type forest
 subtype copy
 <template>
 <store>
    @type file
    @id "test-#{worker_id}"
    @log_level debug
    path "fluentd/log/test-#{worker_id}.*.log"
    append true
 <buffer>
    flush_mode interval
    flush_interval 3
    flush_at_shutdown true
  </buffer>
 <format>
  @type single_value
  message_key log
 </format>
 </store>
 <store>
     @type redis_store
     host server_ip
     port 6379
     key test
     store_type list
 <buffer>
    flush_mode interval
    flush_interval 3
    flush_at_shutdown true
    flush_thread_count 4
  </buffer>
 </store>
  </template>
</match>
</label>
</worker>
```

Any tips how to make throughput to redis better?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the redistore plugin you can get much better performance by installing the hiredis gem which wraps the C redis API

https://github.com/moaikids/fluent-plugin-redisstore

Comment: Thank you, I will try the the plugin you suggested, but until now we used this one https://github.com/pokehanai/fluent-plugin-redis-store. Is there any chance to make it work better? (there is no hiredis) I really dont understand where the problem can be - it just cant send data so quickly so we cant use redis and elk on our environment - it slows down whole fluentd :/.

Comment: Hiredis is going to be way faster than the native ruby redis driver.  At scale, it will really make the difference that you are looking for

Comment: So I tried the plugin that you've mentioned (fluent-plugin-redisstore) and it can't be used with multiworkers -  we need to use MW because of huge amount of data...:/
I tried the second one also, the original.. (fluent-plugin-redis) and that one can use MW but cant be used with LIST....
Do you have any idea how to solve it? I'm quite dissapointed that there is no option for us to set it up right...:(